# What scala solution patterns on android could be used to replace observer pattern?

Tags: android, scala, observer-pattern, reactive-programming

I am learning about scala on android and am looking for a scala design pattern which replaces **my variation** of the observer pattern (as the observer pattern is officially deprecated in scala).

In particular I am struggling with how to handle android service in activity and with the view binding. I have prepared a [repo](https://github.com/dkokic/android-solution-patterns.git) with a simple android app in java using observers and would appreciate any pointers and/or code samples how to implement it in the proper scala way.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a question with a broad answer, but:

- you might want to study Functional Reactive Programming - I always found [Ingo Maier's Deprecating the Observer Pattern paper](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/176887/files/DeprecatingObservers2012.pdf) a nice summary of how it can be done in Scala; you might also want to check out the [ScalaRx library](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx)
- for functional composition of event streams, which is more lightweight than FRP, you might want to study [Reactive Extensions for Scala](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala) or [Reactive Collections](http://reactive-collections.com/) ([source code](https://github.com/storm-enroute/reactive-collections))
- if you want to build distributed event-driven systems, consider taking a look at Akka

Note that the observer pattern is not deprecated in Scala -- it is a design pattern that you are free to use in any language, including Scala. It's just that Scala is more amenable for higher-level abstractions than other languages, so you can easily use those instead of the observer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am aware of ReactiveX and akka implementation, but still struggle to apply all great FRP concepts on such a simple platform like android. *btw if you look in ObservableSet and ObservableMap classes in 2.11 then you know what I mean ;-)*

Comment: I think you should take a look at `ReactMap` and `ReactSet` in Reactive Collections if you want something really powerful. Though, if you are worried about application footprint, `ObservableMap` and `ObservableSet` might be sufficient for you, particularly if you are deploying an Android app.